# Can I use a pair of adamantine daggers to help climb a wall?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, special-materials

If I have a pair of adamantine daggers could I use them to help with my skill check to climb a stone wall? Or do I have to reduce the hp of the wall to 0 to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**There's no specific rule to cover this, but your GM could reasonably let you use them somehow.**

It's plausible that you could use the daggers as improvised tools to assist your climbing, but there is no specific rule which addresses doing this; judgement on the part of the GM is required.

For many skills, climb included, you can get a +2 circumstance bonus if you have an appropriate tool or kit to use in the attempt. Having a [climber's kit](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#climbersKit) grants this bonus to climbing checks. Your GM might rule that a pair of adamantine daggers you can drive into the wall relatively easily to use as handholds is equivalent to having a climber's kit, and so give you a +2 bonus.

Alternatively, the Climb skill does have a section on making your own handholds and footholds, which states:

> *[Making Your Own Handholds and Footholds](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/climb.htm#makingYourOwnHandholdsandFootholds)*
>
> You can make your own handholds and footholds by pounding pitons into a wall. Doing so takes 1 minute per piton, and one piton is needed per 3 feet of distance. As with any surface that offers handholds and footholds, a wall with pitons in it has a DC of 15. In the same way, a climber with a handaxe or similar implement can cut handholds in an ice wall.

Normally this requires pitons which you embed and leave in the wall (so doesn't work with just two daggers), but it does allow for a character climbing up an ice wall, specifically, to cut their own handholds using an appropriate tool. With an adamantine weapon, it is easy to imagine that you could do the same thing to rock and other walls, so you could chisel out handholds and footholds as you go. It would take a very long time, since you'd be taking a minute or so for every three feet of climbing distance in order to chisel out a decent gap to use, but the DC would be reduced to only 15, and the handholds/footholds could then also be used by following party members to make getting up the wall easier.

Comment: The making handholds / ice climbing reference seems especially relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to reduce the hp of the wall to 0!  You can't climb it once you've done that because then it's destroyed and there's no wall left to climb.  You *can* try to use your daggers to help you climb, and the DM may apply a circumstance bonus to your climb check (up to a +2) and/or lower the DC by as much as 2.  Circumstance bonuses stack, so this would be in addition to the bonus granted by your climber's kit, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

As DM I wouldn't allow it. Reason is stone can't easily be cut into the way needed to create handles to "climb" a stone wall.

On the other hand....

Wood (or similar) absolutely. Each time rolling for strength to see if it gets lodged in far enough to hold the characters weight including carried objects, as well as, a dex throw to see if the player falls while pulling the dagger out before moving it up the wall and repeating the actions.

Conclusion: DMs discretion but if it's solid then it doesn't make sense.  Stone is no, use Pitons. Wood or similar yes.

Have fun and Enjoy!